# how can I create a fancybox confirm box for ajax   delete Rails 3

Tags: ajax, fancybox

I would like to us Fancybox for confirm messages before a user deletes something.

I am a NOOB so not sure how to stop an ajax request to delete something stop and wait for a user to click 'confirm' on a fancybox modal window.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

THanks

I am using Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This script](http://snipplr.com/view/29911/javascript-alert-and-confirm-dialog-the-fancybox-way/) looks like a condensed and easy way to get where you are going to.

From what I see, you should be running the script before you delete something, so you don't have try to stop the request and wait for the user.

For example, when the user clicks the button, you don't delete anything until the confirm button is checked. That way, you are making less requests (faster load time) and you are saving yourself some coding.

Comment: I am using an AJAX submit with Rails 3 so its not so easy to stop the request.  The above works if the form is not submitting with ajax I guess.

Comment: I think I just understood what you meant.  I change the code for the delete button to call this fancybox popup.  If the user clicks ok then call the function that deletes the item. Else do nothing.

Comment: Yes. That way you are saving some time.